# C# WPF, ListView and GridView, dynamic columns, and issues with data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, class, listview, gridview

I have a custom class:

```
public class myField {
    public string MyName;
    public string MyDataType;
    public Field details;
}
```

The custom class "Field" is defined from an imported Salesforce.com Partner WSDL. It looks something like this:

```
public class Field {
    public string name;
    public string label;
    public string type;
    public int length;
    public bool custom;
    ... // there are probably 50+ defined properties here
}
```

I have created a list of myField objects, to hold a list of these fields:

```
public List<myField> MasterList = new List<myField>();
```

This list is populated through some API calls, I have validated that the data is there and is not null.

My goal is to show the fields "MyName", "MyDataType", as well as all of the sub-properties under the "details" field, in a ListView.

```
public GridView myGridView = new GridView();
GridViewColumn theColumn;

theColumn = new GridViewColumn();
theColumn.Header = "MyName";
theColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("MyName");
myGridView.Columns.Add(theColumn);

theColumn = new GridViewColumn();
theColumn.Header = "length";
theColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("details.length");
myGridView.Columns.Add(theColumn);

myListView.View = myGridView;
myListView.ItemsSource = MasterList;
```

The problem that I have, is that any Main Properties that I try to display work just fine (MyName, MyDataType), but any sub-properties (sub-fields that I pull through the "details" field) do NOT display at all (name, label, type, length, custom, etc).

```
binding = "MyName" // displays correctly
binding = "MyDataType" // displays correctly
binding = "details.name" // does not display correctly
binding = "details.label" // does not display correctly
etc
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure those properties in the `Field` class is indeed ***properties***? If you are showing the actual code then those are fields, not properties. Binding only works on properties

Comment: I'm honestly not sure... if we assume they are not properties, is there a way to expose them as properties somehow?

Comment: Actually, I take it back. The Visual Studio interface states that they are indeed properties.

Comment: The most simply way to define a property is using the [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) i.e. `public string name {get; set;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and even the `MyName` and `MyDataType` failed to display, unless I change them to below

```
public class myField {
    public string MyName {get; set;}
    public string MyDataType {get; set;}
    public Field details {get; set;}
}

public class Field {
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string label {get; set;}
    public string type {get; set;}
    public int length {get; set;}
    public bool custom {get; set;}
}
```

Then everything works just fine

Comment: This is the solution. The "details" property needed to have get; and set; methods added to it. (my example was simplified, and I didn't write my get and set methods for the other fields, to try to keep things brief)Thank you, Evan!